# What was the name of the helping alien race in The Fifth Element?

Tags: the-fifth-element

In the Fifth Element, what was the name of the alien crew that came to help the human race when the great Evil returned?

Comment: Did you even look?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but have to agree with @JohnP. The race is called by name several times throughout the movie, and is easily found via google search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The race was known as the **Mondoshawan**.

From the [original script](http://sfy.ru/?script=fifth_element);

> **CORNELIUS:** (to the President) *The Mondoshawans don't belong to the Federated Territories, but they are peaceful... in their
>   possession are the four elements of life. These elements when they are
>   gathered around a fifth: The Supreme Being, ultimate warrior, created
>   to protect life......*

[image]

They are [described](http://moa.omnimulti.com/Mondoshawan) as;

> *"an alien species [...that...] had existed
>   for countless years. They served as the protectors and guardians of a
>   weapon that was arranged around four elements; fire, water, air and
>   earth that surrounded the fifth element which was a supreme being and a
>   member of the Mondoshawan race. This was done so in order to combat
>   the Great Evil that approached every five millenia. The Fifth Element
>   thus created what was known as the Light of Creation that destroyed
>   the Great Evil as well as brought life to every corner of the cosmos."*

The DVD contained an extensive '[Making of](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgi7JeDpwxM)" documentary titled "**The Fifth Element : Creating the Mondoshawans**" in which Nick Dudman (Creature Effects Supervisor for 5th Element) and Monique Brown (Animatronic Designer) discuss the difficulties of building and operating the models.

In the official Soundtrack, they have their own theme music entitled "[Mondoshawan](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3IkhDMg_gE)" which contains a mixture of descending tones and Mondoshawan language.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that the Mondoshawans had a perfect genetic structure. That only applied to Leloo, and she was NOT a Mondoshawan. Whoever put that part in the wiki article had it wrong.

Comment: @Omegacron - I agree and have edited out accordingly.

Comment: in that case, +1 from me!

Answer (score 4):

The alien species is the Mondoshawans.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fifth_Element